# Shared classes are build under VS2008 only but not under MSBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wcf, silverlight, msbuild

We share our classes between silverlight 3.0 client and server as is it described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889621/adding-service-references-to-multiple-wcf-services-that-shared-classes). **Everything works fine under Visual Studio 2008 only.** Using msbuild  with following command line parameters:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe FoobarApplication.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"`

we get following error:

```
Class1.cs(28,54): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WcfService' does not exist in the namespace 'Company.FoobarApplication' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Service References\geoServiceReference1\Reference.cs(24,81): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WcfService' does not exist in the namespace 'Company.FoobarApplication' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Done Building Project "C:\work\bov-tmp\FoobarApplication\SilverlightClassLibrary3\SilverlightClassLibrary3.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.

Done Building Project "C:\work\bov-tmp\FoobarApplication\FoobarApplication.sln" (Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

I found [exactly the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517309/silverlight-project-builds-in-vs2008-but-fails-when-using-msbuild) here. There are 4 workarounds [there](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/964125/EN-US), I tried first 3 of them and those did not worked out. The 4-th workaround is not the acceptable solution.

Any thoughts how to build the solution?

Comment: Resolved the problem. The geoServiceReference1 project was referencing our RUI.Web project. That stupid reference appeared somehow after the solution reorganization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem. The geoServiceReference1 project was referencing our RUI.Web project. That stupid reference appeared somehow after the solution reorganization.